# char* (Array) cast to unsigned long + 1?

Tags: java, c, arrays, casting, porting

I'm trying to port some C code to Java, however I've been struggling to figure out what these lines of code do.

Note: `rawEntry` is of type `char*` and appears to be a 12 bytes long allocated as such

```
char *rawEntry = (char*)malloc(0x000c);
```

---

```
unsigned long *l;
unsigned long offset;

// ...

l = (unsigned long*) rawEntry + 1;
offset = ntohl(*l);
```

As far as I can tell, it takes the first four items of the array, and puts them together to form a long, however my attempts in java have been less than successful.

```
offset = (rawEntry[0] << 24) +
         (rawEntry[1] << 16) +
         (rawEntry[2] << 8) +
         (rawEntry[3]) +
         1;
```

When presented with the following array,

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 -38
```

The C code outputs 3034 as the offset
My Java code outputs 16777217, or 1 if I flip the endian

Comment: `rawEntry` could be a `char *` or an array of `char`, but not both.  The distinction might not matter for your particular task, but then again, it might.  It's hard for us to tell, because you have not really given us much to work with.

Comment: `char *rawEntry = (char*) malloc(0x000c);` - This is how `rawEntry` is allocated @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression

```
l = (unsigned long*) rawEntry + 1;
```

casts `rawEntry` to pointer to a type that has size of 8 bytes on your system. After that, adding `1` means adding 8 bytes, so the actual conversion looks like this:

```
offset = (Byte.toUnsignedInt(rawEntry[ 8]) << 24) +
         (Byte.toUnsignedInt(rawEntry[ 9]) << 16) +
         (Byte.toUnsignedInt(rawEntry[10]) <<  8) +
         (Byte.toUnsignedInt(rawEntry[11]) <<  0);
```

The following four bytes are interpreted as `3034`:

```
0 0 11 -38
```

You should be able to simplify this further by using `ByteBuffer`:

```
int offset = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawEntry, 8, 4).getInt();
```

Comment: On the contrary, cast operators have higher precedence than addition.  The expression you highlight is equivalent to `((unsigned long*) rawEntry) + 1`.  And of course, one must be mindful of the semantics of pointer addition.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are right.  Working back from his output it looks like `unsigned long` has size of 8 on OP's system.

Comment: `(rawEntry[8] << 24) + (rawEntry[9] << 16) + (rawEntry[10] << 8) + (rawEntry[11])` results in 2778

Comment: @CraftedCart That's because you convert a signed `byte` to signed `int`. Use `Byte.toUnsignedInt` around each element of `rawEntry`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Aha! That was it - Thanks :)

Comment: Then uhh... The next line after that says `l = (unsigned long*) rawEntry + 2`
Soo... `rawEntry[16]`... Which doesn't exist... - There was a little table in the docs saying it expected a value at offset 4 (not 8)... Perhaps whoever developed this always expected a long to be 4 bytes?... That would explain why this thingy crashes on me

Comment: @CraftedCart Yes, that's very possible. It looks like the code that reads network data is dependent on the hardware. P.S. Take a look at the edit, this should be an easier way to read `int`s from your byte buffer. If you read your data sequentially, you should be able to do all your reading through `ByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 2):

Before going further it is important to note that this code depends on the actual magnitude of a `long` on your platform. On 64 bits platforms longs are 64 bits, that is a `long` takes up 8 bytes. On the other hand `ntohl` converts a “network long” that is 32 bits long (4 bytes).

Assuming `rawEntry` is `{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0xB,0xDA,…}` (0xB is the base 16 equivalent of 11, 0xDA is the base 16 (hexadecimal) `unsigned` value that corresponds to -38)

```
l = (unsigned long*) rawEntry + 1;
```

really means that `l` refers to the second `unsigned long`. That is skip the first 8 bytes from `rawEntry` and `l` then points to the `{0,0,0xB,0xDA,…}` part. Now `*l` is the `unsigned long` represented by the `{0,0,0xB,0xDA,…}` bytes sequence and it is dependent on your architecture. If you are on a little endian machine that will be 0x…DA0B0000 (ellipsis because the end of the array is unkown, that is undefined behaviour). And now `ntohl` will just keep the last 32 bits and invert the bytes order resulting in 0x00000BDA or 3034 in base 10.

The easy way to write this in Java would be

```
offset = (rawEntry[8] << 24) +
         (rawEntry[9] << 16) +
         (rawEntry[10] << 8) +
         (rawEntry[11]);
```